# source code translators from a new language to subset of C

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am working on a project which has got a new language implementation. I have been assigned the task to construct a translator for the language. The translator should be built in Java and the translation output should produce the subset of the new language into C. I have few questions regarding that:
1. How to proceed with this?
2. Which phase should I emphasize more on? Should it be code generator phase of the compiler?
3. Do I need to have one more grammar for target language?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd investigate ANTLR, if you're not already at least aware of it.  From http://www.antlr.org/about.html (emphasis mine):

> ANTLR, ANother Tool for Language Recognition, is a language tool that
>   provides a framework for constructing recognizers, compilers, and
>   translators from grammatical descriptions containing actions in a
>   variety of target languages. ANTLR automates the construction of
>   language recognizers. From a formal grammar, ANTLR generates a program
>   that determines whether sentences conform to that language. **In other
>   words, it's a program that writes other programs. By adding code
>   snippets to the grammar, the recognizer becomes a translator or
>   interpreter.** ANTLR provides excellent support for intermediate-form
>   tree construction, tree walking, translation and provides
>   sophisticated automatic error recovery and reporting.

As an added bonus, ANTLR is written in and easily callable by Java.

Additional details are available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR.